# How to fix MySQL error 1064 on import with error near "json DEFAULT NULL' with SQL file generated from 'Export' fufnction in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I generate SQL file from phpmyadmin in one server, but get error 1064 when importing to another phpmyadmin server with error near line "json DEFAULT NULL"

Hi, i was Exporting an SQL file from phpmyadmin, and then imported  it to another server with phpmyadmin but get the following error

I would be thankfull if you could point me where i did wrong.

Thankyou very much.

Error

SQL query:

--

### -- Database: `gitaemr`

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `com_gita_paycheck_staff`

```
CREATE TABLE `com_gita_paycheck_staff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hour` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `shift` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `services` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `sversion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'json DEFAULT NULL,   `sversion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT' at line 15

Comment: Which MariaDB version are you running (`SELECT VERSION();`) because JSON datatype is MariaDB 10.2.7+ see [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/)

Comment: As workaround you could replace it as `CREATE TABLE com_gita_paycheck_staff (
  services LONGTEXT, 
  CHECK (JSON_VALID(services))
);` .. Because `JSON` is a dropin replaced for `LONGTEXT` in MariaDB

Comment: 10.1.38-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: I see, seems like my db need to be updated. Thank you very much

Comment: So supposed to be i changed all the json into longtext, do i need to modify my php code? I write the data using json_encode before inserting to the db, and read it by json_decode it

Answer (score 0):

you can change json to array, yes it's because of MariaDB Version on Debian stable has no json

Comment: *"you can change json to array"* Array as in `ARRAY` datatype SQL 1999 standard?, i believe MariaDB does not support that feature?

Comment: I see, thank you Michael. Now if i replace json with array, do i need to modify my php code since i turn the data into json_encode function, and read it using json_decode function. It would be a hassle

Comment: json_encode($row); yes you need this if your code needs json

Comment: You ca upgrade to mariadb 10.3 stable, but there is no going back!!! You can not downgrade, so be carefull if you whant to do that.
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=herrbischoff&distro=Debian&distro_release=stretch--stretch&version=10.3